# How to prevent session from running out when translating big files

Tags: autodesk-forge

I am trying to translate bigger files, but it takes longer than 60 minutes and when the token runs out the translation is stuck. How to prevent this?

I use the GUI of Forge Autodesk to translate Revit files to svf files which are viewable by the Forge Viewer

Comment: Can you give some examples?

Comment: you mean files? I am sorry but they are confidential. I am trying to remove the time limit to enable larger translations

Comment: Ok then can you add your process of translation to the question?

Comment: it is the basic GUI of Forge Autodesk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The translation process itself should not be affected, meaning as long as you use a valid token when calling [POST Job](https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/job-POST/) the translation should run with that token.

If during the translation your token expires and you need to check the translation progress via [GET Manifest](https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/urn-manifest-GET/), then you need to refresh the token. Better yet, you should be using [Derivative Webhook](https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/webhooks/v1/tutorials/create-a-hook-model-derivative/) to be notified when your extraction finishes.